# ios animation - display image/fill color from left to right with animating

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, calayer

I have a image, been added to CALayer.contents.
The image basically contains a word/letters, the requirement is to animate like showing up letters from left to right gradually, mean while animating the image positions as like initially 1st letter on the middle and eventually whole image been at central position.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this with Core animation? Code snippets will be greatly appreciated.

One thought I had is to set the image colour same as background colour at initial state(looks transparent), and fill image colour to desired colour from left to right with animation.  And at the same time animate the image position.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a gradient layer as a mask, then animating the position of the image layer and the locations of the gradient.

Here's a quick example to get started:

```
class RevealView: UIView {
    
    public var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imgLayer.contents = image?.cgImage
        }
    }
    public var duration: TimeInterval = 1.0
    
    private let gradLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    private let imgLayer = CALayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {

        clipsToBounds = true

        layer.addSublayer(imgLayer)
        imgLayer.contentsGravity = .resize
        
        // white area shows through, clear area is "hidden"
        gradLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
        // left-to-right gradient
        gradLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        // start locations so entire layer is masked
        gradLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.0]
        // set the mask
        layer.mask = gradLayer
        
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // set image layer frame to view bounds
        imgLayer.frame = bounds
        // move it half-way to the right
        imgLayer.position.x = bounds.maxX
        // set gradient layer frame to view bounds
        gradLayer.frame = bounds
    }
    
    public func doAnim() {
        
        let imgAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
        let gradAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
        
        // animate image layer from right-to-left
        imgAnim.toValue = bounds.midX
        // animate gradient from left-to-right
        gradAnim.toValue = [NSNumber(value: 1.0), NSNumber(value: 2.0)]

        imgAnim.duration = self.duration
        gradAnim.duration = imgAnim.duration * 2.0
        
        [imgAnim, gradAnim].forEach { anim in
            anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            anim.fillMode = .forwards
            anim.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        }
        
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        
        imgLayer.add(imgAnim, forKey: nil)
        gradLayer.add(gradAnim, forKey: nil)
        
        CATransaction.commit()

    }
}

class RevealVC: UIViewController {
    
    let testView = RevealView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "mt") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!")
        }
        testView.image = img
        
        // use longer or shorter animation duration if desired (default is 1.0)
        //testView.duration = 3.0
        
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        testView.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: img.size.width),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: img.size.height),
        ])
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        testView.doAnim()
    }
}
```